# Rundeck, error interno 500 CentOS

Tags: linux, servidor, grails, centos7

Buen dia
Cada que trato de correr un trabajo con Rundeck, lo que sea, me sale el siguiente error.
"javax.servlet.ServletException"

Dice que es causado por lo siguiente
"Could not resolve view with name 'downloadOutput' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'"

Mi rundeck

Rundeck version: 3.0.13-20190123
install type: rpm
OS Name/version: CentOS 7

Para reproducir el error solo basta tener una instalación limpia de rundeck, crear cualquier trabajo y correrlo, incluso si solo es un comando para los nodos, me da el mismo error.

Este es el trace que se genera a partir del error

> `Line | Method
>   ->> 108 | doFilter in org.springframework.security.web.jaasapi.JaasApiIntegrationFilter
>
> | 1642 | doFilter in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 55 |
>   doFilterInternal in
>   org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter |
>   107 | doFilter in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
>   | 1642 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | -1 | call in
>   javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter | 67 | doFilterInternal in
>   org.rundeck.grails.plugins.securityheaders.RundeckSecurityHeadersFilter
>   | 107 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter | 1642 | doFilter
>   . . . . in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 111
>   | doFilterInternal in
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter | 107 |
>   doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter | 1642 | doFilter
>   in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 317 |
>   doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   127 | invoke in
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor
>   | 91 | doFilter . . . . in '' | 331 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   114 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter |
>   64 | doFilter in
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter
>   | 331 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   54 | doFilterInternal in
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsHttpPutFormContentFilter
>   | 107 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter | 331 | doFilter
>   in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   54 | doFilter . . . . in
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
>   | 331 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   158 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter
>   | 331 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   170 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
>   | 331 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   96 | run . . . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.jaasapi.JaasApiIntegrationFilter$1 |
>   -2 | doPrivileged in java.security.AccessController | 422 | doAs . . . . . . in javax.security.auth.Subject | 105 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.security.web.jaasapi.JaasApiIntegrationFilter |
>   331 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   200 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter
>   | 331 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   64 | doFilter in
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
>   | 331 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   105 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
>   | 331 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   58 | doFilter in
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter | 331 |
>   doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   214 | doFilterInternal in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy | 177 | doFilter . .
>   . . in '' | 1642 | doFilter in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 77 |
>   doFilterInternal in org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter
>   | 107 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter | 1642 | doFilter
>   . . . . in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 67 |
>   doFilterInternal in org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter |
>   107 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter | 1642 | doFilter
>   in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 197 |
>   doFilterInternal in
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter | 107 |
>   doFilter in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter | 1642
>   | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 96 |
>   doFilterInternal in org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter | 107 |
>   doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter | 1642 | doFilter
>   in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 103 |
>   doFilterInternal in
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter | 107 |
>   doFilter in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter | 1642
>   | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 533 | doHandle
>   in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler | 146 | handle . . . . .
>   in org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler | 548 | handle in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler | 132 | handle . . . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper | 257 | nextHandle in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler | 1595 | doHandle . . .
>   . in org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler | 255 |
>   nextHandle in org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler | 1317 |
>   doHandle . . . . in org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler |
>   203 | nextScope in org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler |
>   473 | doScope . . . . in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler |
>   1564 | doScope in org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler |
>   201 | nextScope . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler | 1219 | doScope in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler | 144 | handle . . . .
>   . in org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler | 132 | handle in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper | 531 | handle . . . .
>   . in org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server | 352 | handle in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel | 260 | onFillable . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection | 281 | succeeded in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback | 102 | fillable
>   . . . . in org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest | 118 | run in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2 | 333 | runTask . . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill | 310 |
>   doProduce in '' | 168 | tryProduce . . . in '' | 126 | run in '' | 366
>   | run . . . . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread |
>   762 | runJob in org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool | 680 |
>   run . . . . . . in org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2 ^
>   748 | run in java.lang.Thread
>
> Caused by PrivilegedActionException: null
>   ->> -2 | doPrivileged in java.security.AccessController
>
> | 422 | doAs in javax.security.auth.Subject | 105 | doFilter . . . .
>   in org.springframework.security.web.jaasapi.JaasApiIntegrationFilter |
>   1642 | doFilter in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 55 |
>   doFilterInternal in
>   org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter |
>   107 | doFilter in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
>   | 1642 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | -1 | call in
>   javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter | 67 | doFilterInternal in
>   org.rundeck.grails.plugins.securityheaders.RundeckSecurityHeadersFilter
>   | 107 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter | 1642 | doFilter
>   . . . . in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 111
>   | doFilterInternal in
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter | 107 |
>   doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter | 1642 | doFilter
>   in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 317 |
>   doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   127 | invoke in
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor
>   | 91 | doFilter . . . . in '' | 331 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   114 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter |
>   64 | doFilter in
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter
>   | 331 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   54 | doFilterInternal in
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsHttpPutFormContentFilter
>   | 107 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter | 331 | doFilter
>   in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   54 | doFilter . . . . in
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
>   | 331 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   158 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter
>   | 331 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   170 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
>   | 331 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   96 | run . . . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.jaasapi.JaasApiIntegrationFilter$1 |
>   -2 | doPrivileged in java.security.AccessController | 422 | doAs . . . . . . in javax.security.auth.Subject | 105 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.security.web.jaasapi.JaasApiIntegrationFilter |
>   331 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   200 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter
>   | 331 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   64 | doFilter in
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
>   | 331 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   105 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
>   | 331 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   58 | doFilter in
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter | 331 |
>   doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   214 | doFilterInternal in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy | 177 | doFilter . .
>   . . in '' | 1642 | doFilter in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 77 |
>   doFilterInternal in org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter
>   | 107 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter | 1642 | doFilter
>   . . . . in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 67 |
>   doFilterInternal in org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter |
>   107 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter | 1642 | doFilter
>   in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 197 |
>   doFilterInternal in
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter | 107 |
>   doFilter in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter | 1642
>   | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 96 |
>   doFilterInternal in org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter | 107 |
>   doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter | 1642 | doFilter
>   in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 103 |
>   doFilterInternal in
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter | 107 |
>   doFilter in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter | 1642
>   | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 533 | doHandle
>   in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler | 146 | handle . . . . .
>   in org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler | 548 | handle in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler | 132 | handle . . . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper | 257 | nextHandle in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler | 1595 | doHandle . . .
>   . in org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler | 255 |
>   nextHandle in org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler | 1317 |
>   doHandle . . . . in org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler |
>   203 | nextScope in org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler |
>   473 | doScope . . . . in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler |
>   1564 | doScope in org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler |
>   201 | nextScope . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler | 1219 | doScope in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler | 144 | handle . . . .
>   . in org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler | 132 | handle in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper | 531 | handle . . . .
>   . in org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server | 352 | handle in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel | 260 | onFillable . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection | 281 | succeeded in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback | 102 | fillable
>   . . . . in org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest | 118 | run in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2 | 333 | runTask . . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill | 310 |
>   doProduce in '' | 168 | tryProduce . . . in '' | 126 | run in '' | 366
>   | run . . . . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread |
>   762 | runJob in org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool | 680 |
>   run . . . . . . in org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2 ^
>   748 | run in java.lang.Thread
>
> Caused by ServletException: Could not resolve view with name
>   'downloadOutput' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
>   ->> 1266 | render in org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
>
> | 1041 | processDispatchResult in '' | 984 | doDispatch . . . in '' |
>   901 | doService in '' | 970 | processRequest . in
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet | 861 | doGet in '' |
>   687 | service . . . . in javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet | 846 |
>   service in org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet | 790 |
>   service . . . . in javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet | 865 | handle in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder | 1655 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 215 | doFilter
>   in org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter | 1642 |
>   doFilter . . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 96 | run in
>   org.springframework.security.web.jaasapi.JaasApiIntegrationFilter$1 |
>   -2 | doPrivileged . . in java.security.AccessController | 422 | doAs in javax.security.auth.Subject | 105 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.jaasapi.JaasApiIntegrationFilter |
>   1642 | doFilter in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 55 |
>   doFilterInternal in
>   org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter |
>   107 | doFilter in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
>   | 1642 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | -1 | call in
>   javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter | 67 | doFilterInternal in
>   org.rundeck.grails.plugins.securityheaders.RundeckSecurityHeadersFilter
>   | 107 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter | 1642 | doFilter
>   . . . . in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 111
>   | doFilterInternal in
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter | 107 |
>   doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter | 1642 | doFilter
>   in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 317 |
>   doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   127 | invoke in
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor
>   | 91 | doFilter . . . . in '' | 331 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   114 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter |
>   64 | doFilter in
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter
>   | 331 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   54 | doFilterInternal in
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsHttpPutFormContentFilter
>   | 107 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter | 331 | doFilter
>   in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   54 | doFilter . . . . in
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
>   | 331 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   158 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter
>   | 331 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   170 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
>   | 331 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   96 | run . . . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.jaasapi.JaasApiIntegrationFilter$1 |
>   -2 | doPrivileged in java.security.AccessController | 422 | doAs . . . . . . in javax.security.auth.Subject | 105 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.security.web.jaasapi.JaasApiIntegrationFilter |
>   331 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   200 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter
>   | 331 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   64 | doFilter in
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
>   | 331 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   105 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
>   | 331 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   58 | doFilter in
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter | 331 |
>   doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain |
>   214 | doFilterInternal in
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy | 177 | doFilter . .
>   . . in '' | 1642 | doFilter in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 77 |
>   doFilterInternal in org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter
>   | 107 | doFilter in
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter | 1642 | doFilter
>   . . . . in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 67 |
>   doFilterInternal in org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter |
>   107 | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter | 1642 | doFilter
>   in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 197 |
>   doFilterInternal in
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter | 107 |
>   doFilter in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter | 1642
>   | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 96 |
>   doFilterInternal in org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter | 107 |
>   doFilter . . . . in
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter | 1642 | doFilter
>   in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 103 |
>   doFilterInternal in
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter | 107 |
>   doFilter in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter | 1642
>   | doFilter . . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain | 533 | doHandle
>   in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler | 146 | handle . . . . .
>   in org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler | 548 | handle in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler | 132 | handle . . . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper | 257 | nextHandle in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler | 1595 | doHandle . . .
>   . in org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler | 255 |
>   nextHandle in org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler | 1317 |
>   doHandle . . . . in org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler |
>   203 | nextScope in org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler |
>   473 | doScope . . . . in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler |
>   1564 | doScope in org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler |
>   201 | nextScope . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler | 1219 | doScope in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler | 144 | handle . . . .
>   . in org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler | 132 | handle in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper | 531 | handle . . . .
>   . in org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server | 352 | handle in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel | 260 | onFillable . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection | 281 | succeeded in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback | 102 | fillable
>   . . . . in org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest | 118 | run in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2 | 333 | runTask . . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill | 310 |
>   doProduce in '' | 168 | tryProduce . . . in '' | 126 | run in '' | 366
>   | run . . . . . . in
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread |
>   762 | runJob in org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool | 680 |
>   run . . . . . . in org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2 ^
>   748 | run in java.lang.Thread`

Answer (score 0):

Logre que funcionara
El problema fue que elimine la linea de
grails.serverURL=http://rundeck.example.com:4440

Si la vuelvo a agregar, solo tengo problemas de redireccionamiento, pero funciona.